# How to represent a negative hexadecimal number?

Tags: hex, decimal

If I have a negative decimal number, say -5 for example, and converted it to hexadecimal format. Would I be able to simply put a negative sign in front of the hexadecimal number? Or is there another way of doing it like with 2's compliment in binary?

Comment: typically we use hex format for representation of a number and thus would not put a negative sign. rather as you suggested you would set the hex value based on representation.

Comment: dec to hex converter http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no "one way" to represent a negative number.  That said there are a number of standard ways to represent a negative number.  To keep the math simple, I'm going to assume that all number use 4 bits.

1. Use a sign bit (in binary) `0111` is 7, but `1111` is -7.  (also can be done in reverse `0111` is -7 `1111` is 7.
2. Use the 1's complement.  `0111` is 7, but `1000` is -7 (all bits flipped.  This has the odd property of `0000` being a natural 0, but `1111` being a (negative zero) -0.
3. Use the 2's complement.  Negation is 1's complement plus one, so `0111` is 7, but `1000 + 0001` or `1001` is -7.  This leverages integer overflow to maintain no negative zero.  `0000` negated is `1111 + 0001` which overflows to `0000`.  It also has a few nice properties such that adding some number plus its negative resolves to zero, provided that both numbers can be written (there is one more negative number than a positive one).  7 + (-7) is `0111 + 1001` which overflows to 0 `0000`.

You may hear the saying that the "bits mean whatever you want them to mean".  This means that you can come up with any number of ways to represent anything, you just build a "map" of the bits to the values you desire.  For example, here is an odd, whimsical way of representing prime numbers.

```
(bits) => value
0001 => 2
0010 => 3
0011 => 5
0100 => 7
0101 => 11
0110 => 13
0111 => 17
(and so on)
```

Such a system would be hard to do math with, but it is an example that you don't have to be constrained to a specific way of doing anything.  As long as you build routines to produce the expected output from the expected input, you can make the mapping of bits to values mean what ever you want it to mean.

This idea of meaning being a thing you impose upon the bits is important.  When you start to deal with text, the "encoding" is the meaning imposed upon the bits storing text, with the same bits sometimes encoding different letters in different encoding schemes.

Comment: You didn't answer the question. It was about hexadecimal. You gave a workaround answer with binary. There are of course ways to handle negative numbers in hexadecimal which you skirted by saying it's whatever you want it to be. The op was looking for specific examples of how others have done it. For that reason, I downvoted.

Comment: @GeorgeXavier That "workaround" is exactly how Intel CPUs are designed to do it.  As is nearly every CPU made in the last 15 years, so I can't imagine you know much about the subject.  2's complement is preferred over other choices, as you get only one (positive) zero.

Comment: He does not ask how a computer does it. He asks in theory how one may notate it. He is specifically referring to hex as i previously mentioned.

Comment: @GeorgeXavier Hexadecimal is just a different reprsentation of bits.  1010 = A doesn't mean the computer stores an 'A' anywhere, it stores four bits, '1010'  So, to "represent a negative number in Hexidecimal" one generally has to decide which encoding in binary that will be used, and then transcribe that encoding into hexidecimal.  In my example -4 encoded in sign-bit notation 1100 would be hex 'C' while -4 encoded in 1's compliment would be 1011, or hex 'B', and finally -4 encoded in 2's compliment would be 1100 or hex 'C'.  Note it's just a coincidence that two of these encodings are 'C'.